# How can i +1, to int look like this 00250

Tags: python, logic

I need to plus 1 to this '00250' and get '00251', and not '251', i trying to make it with separating zero and other digits, and cant :(

I trying to separate it from zero`s like 00251 --> 00|251 --> 00|252 --> 00252, but if we make to 00999, im getting 001000, but 01000 needed

Comment: @sj95126 exactly - `str.zfill()` is the way to go here

Comment: Thank you, `zfill()` , probably looks good in my situation!

Comment: @muhyrla, or you can use formatting `f"{int(value) + 1:05}"`

Answer (score 0):

you can just use format() on result, for example `'{:05}'.format(result)` for 5 digit numbers